# Placing buttons where i want them in Android XML?

Tags: android, xml

I am now having some problems when I want to create my application for android that when I am making my layout in XML i am having trouble that in Eclipse its not latting me place the buttons next to each other side to side it only let me place them under each other. And I did chech that fill parrent was not checked I used only wrap content, ut still it's not letting me place them side to side.

And I didn't find how i would fix this when i search on the web. But maybe here someone can explain what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have an outer `LinearLayout` with a vertical orientation (`android:orientation="vertical"` in the XML source). That puts each child of it below the last one. Change this to `horizontal` to align the buttons next to each other
or use a different parent layout.

Comment: Is there a way i can add so i can place them vertical and horizontal depending on what i feel for?

Comment: You can only have one orientation per LinearLayout. You can nest the LinearLayouts to your liking, but thats bad practice. Check out the `RelativeLayout`, as the name suggest, that lets you put Buttons relative to each other (*"I want this button to the right of the other one, and one below this"*). You also can align the buttons relative to the parent layout (*"Put this in the top-left corner"*).

Comment: Heres a small introduction to RelativeLayout, since it's usually a bit confusing at the start: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html